# Calculating partition function of the Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

I have that the energy of my model is such that every spin interact with each other:

\begin{equation}
E = -\frac{J}{2N}\left(\sum_{i}\sigma_i \right)^2 - h\sum_i\sigma_i
\end{equation}

And I have to prove that the partition function $Z$, that is defined as,

\begin{equation}
Z = \sum_{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_N}e^{-\beta E}
\end{equation}

Can be put in the form

\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\left[2\cosh \left(\beta h + 2x\sqrt{\frac{\beta J}{2N}}\right)\right]^N\mathrm {dx}
\end{equation}

Where we use the Gaussian relation

\begin{equation}
e^{y^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2 + 2yx}\mathrm {dx}
\end{equation}

I tried to put $y = \sum_i \sigma_i$ working the partition function. If you put that energie in the partition function then $Z$ become

\begin{equation}
Z = \sum_{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_N}e^{-\beta E} = \sum_{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_N}\exp \left\{\frac{\beta J}{2N}\left (\sum_i \sigma_i\right)^2 + \beta h \sum_i \sigma_i \right\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=  \sum_{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\exp\left\{2x\sqrt{\frac{\beta J}{2N}}\sum_i \sigma_i\right\}\mathrm{d}x \exp\left\{\beta h \sum_i \sigma_i\right\}
\end{equation}

Where I just used the relation above. What I cannot understand is from where the $\cosh$ came from: The sigmas sum and the other some can be put together in the form 
\begin{equation}\label{equação seis}
Z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\left\{\sum_{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_N}\exp\left(\left(2\sqrt{\frac{\beta J }{2N}}+\beta h\right)\sum_i \sigma_i\right)\right\}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

trivially. Then what I want to know is that how can I prove now that that part will became equal to the $\cosh$ part.

Comment: Just apply the Gaussian relation to the first part of the Boltzmann weight (corresponding to the quadratic part of the Hamiltonian). If you can't do it, this is explained in _many_ textbooks (just google Hubbard-Stratonovich).

Comment: I will try do this.

Comment: Worked but now I ended up having to show that equality

Comment: Do you mean the Gaussian relation? Just bring the $e^{y^2}$ to the other side and observe that the exponent becomes $-(x+y)^2$. Change variables to $z=x+y$ and the result follows immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize you had changed your question. Well, now you just have to sum over the spin values. Note that the function you are summing can be factorized: $e^{A\sum_i \sigma_i} = \prod_i e^{A\sigma_i}$.This means that you can sum over each spin separately.